Función para determinar si existen valores superiores a otro dado
Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

Una empresa tiene guardado un registro con sus ingresos durante el año 2022.
Los datos los tiene guardados en una tabla como la siguiente:
let ingresos = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];

let valorDado = 5000;

Haz una función que dada la tabla con los ingresos semanales y un valor, retorne si hay alguna semana con ingresos superiores al valor dado.
La llamada a la función será algo como esto:
console.log(ingresosMayores(ingresos,valorDado));


Yo he hecho intentos con el Math.apply.max y no me funciona. Éste me dice que la palabra ingresos ya ha sido utilizada, ¿por qué puede ser?
Éste es el código que he intentado:


function ingresosMayores(ingresos, valorDado) {
  let ingresos = [7965, 8714, 8446, 2612, 7241, 2872, 2008, 4857, 4896, 4986, 5746, 6676, 5285, 4427, 5843, 8285, 8601, 5245, 7582, 9616, 3245, 9253, 6749, 2109, 9709, 6883, 4239, 3458, 1215, 9451, 3573, 7977, 5037, 7242, 7380, 3856, 3444, 5911, 5452, 9878, 5781, 2218, 7557, 5580, 6199, 6821, 2204, 2305, 8746, 7637, 8682, 4409, 4749];
  let valorDado = 5000;
  if ingresos > valorDado == ingresosMayores
  return ingresosMayores(ingresos, valorDado));
}
console.log(ingresosMayores(ingresos, valorDado));




Amigo, estas sacando las respuestas de la tarea con IA o como ??

Claramente estas pidiendo como parámetro la palabra "ingresos" y acto seguido, haces una bariable let del mismo nombre "ingresos". El error está clarisimo ahi.

Mismo caso pasa con "valorDado"

Voy a cerrar la otra pregunta cerrada y dejar ésta abierta. Pero, en futuras ocasiones, por favor edita la pregunta original en lugar de crear una nueva con más detalles. Por favor, lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio.

tenía una anterior ? jajaj no la vi.

Ni siquiera copió las correcciones que hice en la otra pregunta, y las he tenido que hacer de nuevo para que la pregunta se vea mejor.

Difícil que haya usado IA. Pase la pregunta por chatGPT y dio un código correcto.

Primero que nada, en tu intento, los valores de ingresos VAN FUERA DE LA FUNCION
De todos modos, modificarla como está no serviría, ya que la evaluación está mal hecha.
Entonces hay que corregir eso...
Primero, vamos a verificar si algún valor dentro de ingresos, es mayor a valorDado, y retornaremos true si ese es el caso.


function ingresosMayores(ingresos, valorDado) {
    return ingresos.some(ingreso => ingreso > valorDado);
}

let ingresos = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];
let valorDado = 5000;

console.log(ingresosMayores(ingresos,valorDado));



Este ejemplo es demasiado simple, pero creo que te van a solicitar realizar la verificación, como te enseñaron en clases. Solo sigue la idea que te acabo de dar, y podrás hacer la verificación como te lo han enseñado en clases.
Ahora, me parece poca información para lo solicitado. Si esta información fuera algo más completa, podrías mostrar el día de la semana incluso, pero como no tenemos eso, podemos solo mostrar el valor.
Entonces, mostraré cuantos valores son mayores al valorDado y mostraremos cuales son esos valores. Para esto, ocuparemos una constante con los valores filtrados (de este modo, no alteramos la primera cadena, sino hacemos otra)


function ingresosMayoresDetalles(ingresos, valorDado) {
    const ingresosFiltrados = ingresos.filter(ingreso => ingreso > valorDado);
    return {
        cantidadSemanas: ingresosFiltrados.length,
        valores: ingresosFiltrados
    };
}

let ingresos = [7965,8714,8446,2612,7241,2872,2008,4857,4896,4986,5746,6676,5285,4427,5843,8285,8601,5245,7582,9616,3245,9253,6749,2109,9709,6883,4239,3458,1215,9451,3573,7977,5037,7242,7380,3856,3444,5911,5452,9878,5781,2218,7557,5580,6199,6821,2204,2305,8746,7637,8682,4409,4749];
let valorDado = 5000;

const resultado = ingresosMayoresDetalles(ingresos, valorDado);
console.log(`Cantidad de semanas: ${resultado.cantidadSemanas}`);
console.log(`Valores: ${resultado.valores}`);



